# What is the correct way to add 2 conditions to this if statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Listed below is the formula where I would like to add 2 more conditions. All tempts have displayed a name error.  I have tried IFS, IF AND functions also.

My goal is to display Low if <1.99, MED if 2 - 2.99 or HIGH if 3.

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])<1.99,"Low","F")
```

Comment: Your logic has 'holes'. It should be `Low if <2, MED if 2 - 2.99 or HIGH if >2.99`. It is very possible that you will get 3 or more decimal places on an average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nested IF:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])<1.99,"Low",IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])<2.99,"Med","High")
```

Comment: Does "Med" need to include 2.99? Assuming all data is rounded to two decimal places, IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM]<3) would probably suffice.

Comment: @JacobEdmond probably but as Jeeped stated there are holes and the OP will need to decide the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

```
=CHOOSE(MAX(1,MIN(3, INT(SUBTOTAL(101, [IM])))), "Low", "Med", "High")
```

Comment: @ScottCraner a little `Max` was missing to complete the (same) idea for that particular case. Now it is bullet-proof and works even with negative subtotals. My motivation into it is to have the calculation of `Subtotal` made only once.

Comment: I like it better than mine, and thought it very clever.

Comment: @ScottCraner it is more worked because of the stated motivation, but your solution is the *natural* one and honestly no one can beat you in immediately catching it  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your logic has holes that are not covered by your rules. I believe it should be closer to **Low if <2, MED if 2 - 2.99 or HIGH if >=3**. It is very possible that you will get 3 or more decimal places on an average.

```
=LOOKUP(SUBTOTAL(101, [IM]), {1E-99,2,3}, {"Low","Med","High"})
```

FWIW, the same can be accomplished by putting `=SUBTOTAL(101, [IM])` in a cell and applying a custom number format of,

```
[Red][<2]Low;[Blue][>=3]\Hi\g\h;\M\e\d
```

I've added red font for Low and blue font for High. The added value here is that despite *displaying* Low, Med or High, the cell contains the underlying average value that can be used in calculations.

Comment: How am I ever going to catch you if you keep coming up with good answers. 8P

Comment: Thanks, I doubt I will ever get the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A, paste this in column B and drag it down:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])<1.99,"LOW",IF(AND(SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])>2,SUBTOTAL(101,[IM])<2.99),"MED","HIGH"))
```